# FastAPI create background task for all routes

Tags: python, fastapi

According to [this tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) you can create `BackgroundTasks` in the route's handler function as follow:

```
@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, email, message="some notification")
    return {"message": "Notification sent in the background"}
```

but in my case, I have a huge number of routes, so I want to centralize the background task in a custom APIRoute (this is a simplified example):

```
# core/users.py
def process(email):
    #processing
    #create a background task here

# router.py
class MyRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            response: Response = await original_route_handler(request)
            return response

    return custom_route_handler

# app.py
from core import users
@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str):
    #processing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the ideas; but according to my use case (the background task is created in a custom APIRoute, after the response is created).

I ended up with something like:

```
# core/users.py
def process(response: Response):
    background_task: BackgroundTask = BackgroundTask(async_process, MY_ARG1)
    if response.background is None:
        response.background = background_task
    else:
        response.background.add_task(background_task.func, *background_task.args, *background_task.kwargs)

# router.py
class MyRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            response: Response = await original_route_handler(request)
            users.process(response=response)
            return response

        return custom_route_handler

# app.py
app = APIRouter(route_class=MyRoute)
@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str):
    #processing
```

PS: These code snippets are a simplified version of what I used in creating a "[trace-module](https://github.com/openreplay/openreplay/blob/5dbb1eeaf154fb404a8b1f6358b609439946ee47/ee/api/or_dependencies.py#L42)" for the [OpenReplay](https://github.com/openreplay/openreplay) project.

Comment: Hi @tahayk, nice solution, good job! However, there is one thing I did not fully understand. Why do you need the if/else in the `process` function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but you should attach the background object to the response. You can check starlette official doc at [Background Tasks](https://www.starlette.io/background/)

```
# core/users.py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

def send_email(email):
    print("sending email to {} as background task!".format(email))

def process(email):
    background_tasks = BackgroundTasks()
    background_tasks.add_task(send_email, email)
    return background_tasks


#app.py
from core import users
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str):
    background_tasks = users.process(email)
    return JSONResponse("Email sent!", background=background_tasks)
```

Answer (score 1):

`BackgroundTasks` is just a helper, you can run it in thread/loop by yourself:

```
def run_in_background(func, *args):
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(func("param"))
    else:
        # Starlette uses anyio library here under the hood
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=("param",))
        t.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

[background task](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) come from [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/background/) and it is attached to a response.

As [fastapi doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) said:

"It's still possible to use BackgroundTask alone in FastAPI, but you have to create the object in your code and return a Starlette Response including it."

you may want to take a look at [runing your function in a threadpool](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1066#issuecomment-612940187) from tiangolo (creator of fastapi)

```py
from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool

@api.get('/handler')
async def handler():
    ...
    # Slow async function
    await my_async_function()
    ....
    # Slow running sync function
    await run_in_threadpool(sync_function)
```